# Get a StreamSocket's Connection Status (UWP)

Tags: c#, sockets, uwp, win-universal-app

I'm using a StreamSocket in a Windows Universal app to make a TCP/IP connection to a text based game (the socket is left open for an extended period of time).  I have it connecting and returning data fine.  Most socket implementations I've used in the past have a property or function (or a way to poll the socket) and get the status (whether it's open, closed, broken, pending, etc.).

I haven't been able to find a way to do this with the StreamSocket.

My question is, How do I query the status of the StreamSocket connection to see if it's dropped (without waiting until I send something down the pipe for it to error out)?

E.g., something so I could do something like:

`if (this.Socket.Status != Status.Connected)`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> `if (this.Socket.Status != Status.Connected)`

The code you wrote was quite elegant , however, as far as I know there is no such api provided by uwp.

The [`Windows.Networking.Sockets`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/networking/sockets) namespace has convenient helper methods and enumerations for handling errors when using sockets and WebSockets. This can be useful for handling specific network exceptions differently in your app.

An error encountered on `DatagramSocket`, `StreamSocket`, or `StreamSocketListener` operation is returned as an `HRESULT` value. The `SocketError.GetStatus` method is used to convert a network error from a socket operation to a `SocketErrorStatus` enumeration value. Most of the `SocketErrorStatus` enumeration values correspond to an error returned by the native Windows sockets operation. An app can filter on specific `SocketErrorStatus` enumeration values to modify app behavior depending on the cause of the exception.

For parameter validation errors, an app can also use the `HRESULT` from the exception to learn more detailed information on the error that caused the exception. Possible `HRESULT` values are listed in the Winerror.h header file. For most parameter validation errors, the `HRESULT` returned is E_INVALIDARG
.

Comment: I accepted the answer, which if I understood what you meant sounds like it's not possible to query the socket's state without first encountering an exception (it doesn't seem like they get thrown until I try to send data after the connection has been broken).

Comment: Subsequent comment for posterity, .Net Standard 2 made this a lot easier to manage.  Using TcpClient and TcpReader it was easier to get the exception from the Disconnect when it occurs without having to send something down the pipe to trigger the exception.